# Reason Page Reloaded

Tags: asp.net

I am porting an application from ASP.NET 2 to ASP.NET 4.5

I have a page that creates a popup windows (Another .aspx page started with the javascript modalWin function).

When the popup is dismissed (using window.close()):

- Under 4.5 the primary page refreshes
- Under 2.0 it does not refresh.

This is a problem because it throws away all the data on the parent page.

How can I determine what it causing the parent page to refresh?

This is difficult for me to debug because I don't know where to set a break point to step thru code to figure out what it is doing.  When I set a break point in the onload= function it just reports the call stack of the page starting the javascript.

I am new to visual studio so please use terminology and instructions that I can see on the screen.

The parent page invokes the popup page like this:

```
<button id="bbb" onclick="button_onclick(this)">Button</button>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
function button_onclick(element) {
    modalWin("popup.aspx", 300, 300);
}
```

When the user clicks the save button on the popup page this javascript runs:

```
function closeit() {
    window.returnValue = true;
    window.close();
}
```

I have dug into the change history of the code and previously the `<button>` button was a image button but the javascript that is invoked did not change.

Comment: You have enough points to know that this question asks for guesses. So: just like any other framework where "something" causes a page to "refresh" look for any code that triggers a `GET` or `POST`. The latter, `POST` is how ASP.Net Web Forms work - which points to _any_ `control` that "submits" (`asp:button`, etc.). What control invokes the "popup"? Inspect that and how it's wired to Javascript, how other events tied to the popup may do so as well. Hth

Comment: Is there a way to use IE developer tools to break on execution of any javascript?

Comment: I personally don't use IE for dev debugging - you can do Javascript  breakpoints in Chrome and FF.  In the code you added, that `button` will `submit`/`POST` (default action if no `type`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"previously the  button was a image button". You seem to mention this in passing almost, but here's your clue. An image with a client-side click event wouldn't cause a postback, because images never do that. Whereas a `<button>` element will, by default, cause a postback, because its default `type` is `submit`. You need to change that to `button` to prevent it.

```
<button type="button" id="bbb" onclick="button_onclick(this)">Button</button>
```

This is the crucial change, and is related to the way the web works in general, not to ASP.NET. The change of .NET Framework is a red herring. The problem does not occur because you changed frameworks, it's because you changed the code

Comment: Thanks.  I was not actually the one that changed the code.  I just phrased it at way for simplicity.  the type=button required on a button seems a bit weird, but a lot of things in web development are a bit weird.

Comment: @MichaelPotter I guess it's less than obvious, I suppose I'm just used to it. The default value is `type="submit"` if you don't set a different one. This causes the button to submit whatever form it is part of. the `button` option effectively tells the page that it's a "button which does something else, not a submit button" Perhaps `other-button` would be a better name for the option, I don't know, I don't write the specs :-). The only other option is `reset` which will cause the button to clear all the fields of its form. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button